# Merging 2 dataframes on Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry I have a very simple question. So I have two dataframes that look like
Dataframe 1:
columns: a b c d e f g h

Dataframe 2:
columns: e ef

I'm trying to join Dataframe 2 on Dataframe 1 at column e, which should yield
columns: a b c d e ef g h
or
columns: a b c d e f g h ef

However: 
df1.merge(df2, how = 'inner', on = 'e') yields a blank dataframe when I print it out.

'outer' merge only extends the dataframe vertically (like using an append function).

Would appreciate some help thank you!

Comment: Can you post some sample data from 'e' column. Check if the values have any trailing spaces and the type of elements are the same in both the dataframes for column 'e'.

Comment: show us a sample of your dataframe 1 and dataframe 2 and your desired output we will have a better idea of the problem

Comment: column e comprises of integers saved in string form for dataframe 1 but integer form for dataframe 2. Oh is that the problem?

Comment: Yup it turns out that was the problem. I just needed to ensure that both were in integer form. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need same `dtypes` of columns for join, so need converting:

```
#convert string column to int
df1['e'] = df1['e'].astype(int)
#inner is default value, so can be omit
df1.merge(df2, on = 'e')
```

Sample:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('abcdef'),
                   'b':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'c':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'd':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'e':['5','3','6','9','2','4'],
                   'f':list('aaabbb'),
                   'g':[1,3,5,7,1,0]})

print (df1)
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g
0  a  4  7  1  5  a  1
1  b  5  8  3  3  a  3
2  c  4  9  5  6  a  5
3  d  5  4  7  9  b  7
4  e  5  2  1  2  b  1
5  f  4  3  0  4  b  0

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ef':[10,30,50,70,10,100],
                   'e':[5,3,6,9,0,7]})
print (df2)
   e   ef
0  5   10
1  3   30
2  6   50
3  9   70
4  0   10
5  7  100
```

---

```
df1['e'] = df1['e'].astype(int)
df = df1.merge(df2, on = 'e') 
print (df)
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  ef
0  a  4  7  1  5  a  1  10
1  b  5  8  3  3  a  3  30
2  c  4  9  5  6  a  5  50
3  d  5  4  7  9  b  7  70
```

Comment: Thanks again Jezrael!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

df1.merge(...)

try:

pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, on ='e', how='inner')

Comment: not necessary, because [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and too [`pandas.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
def mergeDfs(df1,df2):
    newDf = dict()
    dfList = []
    for i in df1:
        l = len(i)
        row = []
        for j in range(l):
            row.append(df1[i][j])
        newDf[i] = row
        dfList.append(i)
    for i in df2:
        l = len(i)
        row = []
        if i not in dfList:
            for j in range(l):
                row.append(df2[i][j])
            newDf[i] = row
    df = pd.DataFrame(newDf)
    return df
```

Comment: i hope this function can help you